# Google Dynamic DNS Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: ip, google, dynamic-dns, domains

I can't get Google's Dynamic DNS API to work for a wildcard domain.

I can get defined subdomains to update their IP just fine but I always get `nohost` when i attempt to update the wildcard's IP.

This page https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en doesn't mention wildcard domains.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick is to create a Synthetic Record for a any subdomain other that `*`.

Create the synthetic record for `wildcard.domainname.com` instead of `*.domainname.com`.

Then create a CNAME record (not synthetic) of the subdomain `*.domain.com` and point it to your synthetic records subdomain `wildcard.domainname.com`.

[image]

The placeholder subdomain `wildcard` could really be anything.

Comment: This also works to add a static ipv6 AAAA Record to wildcard.example.com, for example if you use tunnelbroker.net

Comment: Still working well in 2018

Comment: Received error "Name conflict" as of September 2020 :(

Comment: You can also setup the Dynamic DNS record for `@`, and then make the CNAME record from `*` to `@` to avoid any 'middleman' subdomains.

Comment: works in April 2021 with @GreysonParrelli suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the Google Dynamic DNS "Host name" field blank (empty), click save and it will function like a wildcard (*) for the Google Domain your configuring.